# How really the Machine Learning Engineer work in the job market?

Tags: machine-learning

**i am still student at B.Cs i read some books in addition to attend some courses in Machine Learning my question is:**

- After my gradation job market Machine Learning Engineer Job will be valid to me or must learn some thing else for job market
- What is poplar Field of AI in job Market

Comment: Hi @OsamaMo, welcome to the site. Your question is difficult to answer because it depends on many factors: the content of your degree, the job market in your area, the specific companies, and even the specific positions. Also, it is quite opinion-based. You may want to check [this site's help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for guidelines on how to ask questions that are appropriate for the site.